# Why do we need to make a local copy of smart_ptr first before passing it to other functions?

Tags: c++

[CppCon 2015: Herb Sutter "Writing Good C++14... By Default" Slide 50](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEx5DNLWGgA)

[Live on Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e52369a476b30c0)

I have seen the following guideline through above talk. However, I have hard time to understand the critical issues both solutions try to solve in the first place. All comments on the right side of the code are copied from original talk. Yes, I don't understand the comments on the slide either.

```
void f(int*);
void g(shared_ptr<int>&, int*);
shared_ptr<int> gsp = make_shared<int>();

int main()
{
  // Issue 1>
  f(gsp.get()); // ERROR, arg points to gsp', and gsp is modifiable by f
  // Solution 1>
  auto sp = gsp;
  f(sp.get());  // ok. arg points to sp', and sp is not modifiable by f

  // Issue 2>
  g(sp, sp.get());  // ERROR, arg2 points to sp', and sp is modifiable by f
  // Solution 2>
  g(gsp, sp.get()); // ok, arg2 points to sp', and sp is not modifiable by f
}
```

Can someone please give me some advices what the problems are if we write code shown in Issue 1 and Issue 2 and why the solutions fix the problems?

Comment: Side note: This is an excellent question. I would've completely missed the subtleties in those code examples, and I had to watch that portion of his video a few times to really grok it well enough to write an answer. So thanks for teaching me something today!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`f` could be written like this:

```
void f(int* p)
{
  gsp = nullptr;
  *p = 5;
}
```

Since `gsp` is the only `shared_ptr` that owns the `int`, if it is cleared, then the pointer given to `p` is destroyed.

Basically, it is reasonable for functions which are given non-owning pointers (or references) to expect that the objects being pointed to are owned by someone outside of themselves, and that there is nothing they can do to cause them to be destroyed.

`g` is something similar, though with a reference as a parameter rather than a modifiable global:

```
void g(shared_ptr<int> &sp, int* p)
{
  sp = nullptr;
  *p = 5;
}
```

Both of these are warnings about making sure that, if some code passes an owned object to a function without explicitly transferring ownership, that function *must* ensure that there is nothing the called function can do to destroy that owned object by accident. In real-world scenarios, these will be fair more complex, as far as determining what has actually happened.

For cases of `g`, the parameter might be a reference to some complex object which happens to have the last `shared_ptr` to the `int` you also passed as a parameter. For `f`, the global object might be some "singleton" that manages a bunch of things, including ownership of objects, and this function just so happened to be passed a pointer to such an object. Inadvertently calling the wrong function from `f` or `g` can cause the pointer to become invalid.

Answer (score 6):

Raw pointers have caused a lot of problems in C++. The key problem is that their lifetime is totally unclear. If I have a `T*`, then I have no idea how long that `T` is supposed to live, or if I'm supposed to free it, or if the caller will free it. Messing that up can result in double frees, memory leaks, and in the worst case undefined behavior.

So Herb Sutter, in his presentation, places some basic rules on the use of raw pointers. In particular, he assumes implicitly that raw pointers are *always* borrowed. That is, a `T*` never owns the underlying `T` and hence should never free it. (If you, for some reason, *need* an owned `T*` and can't use a smart pointer, the C++ Core Guidelines recommend using an [`owned<T*>`](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rf-ptr) type to make your intentions clear, even if the `owned` type itself doesn't change anything semantically)

So a `T*` is borrowing data. If we borrow data, we need to know that it will live at least as long as the place we're borrowing it. That's where the top of Slide 50 comes in.

> In callee, **assume** Pointer params are valid for the call, and independent.

So, under Sutter's convention, a function that takes a `T*` should assume that the `T*` is good for *at least* until the function returns.

Now, if I pass the innards of a `shared_ptr`, it's possible that I'll invalidate it accidentally, without even knowing about it.

```
shared_ptr<int> gsp = make_shared<int>();

void f(int* my_pointer) {
  gsp = some_other_data;
  // Oh no! my_pointer is suddenly garbage!
}

int main() {
  f(gsp.get());
}
```

At the "Oh no!" point in the code above, dereferencing `my_pointer` is undefined behavior. But we couldn't have *possibly* known that, since we never actually did anything with that pointer, just with a (theoretically unrelated) pointer.

The data a `shared_ptr` points to is only freed when *all* of the shared pointers referencing it are gone. So by creating a local variable in `main` that also points to the same data, we ensure that the data won't be freed until `main` ends, *even if* the function accidentally invalidates the one reference that it does have access to.

The `g` example is showing that the same thing can happen even without global variables. If a function takes a `std::shared_ptr<T>` and a `T*` that reference the same data, then the former could invalidate the latter *unless* there's another `shared_ptr<T>` somewhere else that the callee *doesn't* have access to that's anchoring it into position.